# Is this theorem wrongly stated on the lecture about Kolmogorov–Smirnov test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm reading Kolmogorov–Smirnov test from a [lecture note](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture14.pdf) from MIT OpenCourseWare [Statistics for Applications](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/). In the lecture note, there are two important theorems:

> [image]

and

> [image]

It's unfortunate that the lecture does not prove Theorem 2. From this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/is-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-valid-with-discrete-distributions), I got that Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is not applicable for non-continuous distributions.
As such, I feel that Theorem 2 is not correct because it does not mention the condition of continuity.

Could you please verify if my observation is correct?

Comment: Re your penultimate paragraph - It rather depends on what you intend by "not applicable". A test using the Komogorov distance will still work (one can in principle evaluate the permutation distribution); you just won't be able to use any of the results that assume continuity (in typical cases it would produce a very conservative test). More detail is in my answer at the post you linked to.